# MagicalRecord UIApplicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I use MagicalRecord as a good library for working with Core Data. My question is how can I save data before my app will enter background. Because I try to write data via block and of course it will not work because the app will be suspended.

So how can I update or put my object in context and save it. Usually I use method that allow import all data from dictionary and save it and it works perfect while app is running.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do this in someplace other than your AppDelegate since you have references to actual data objects. The easiest way I can think of is to listen for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and perform your save operation there. What you may also need to do is use the iOS backgrounding API so that the task can complete while it's running in the background. You may also want to listen to one of the notifications fired prior to actually going into the background as well. `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` seems as appropriate, and you may not have to deal with the backgrounding API.